# logarithm equation with different bases.

Tags: logarithms

Why is this like it is? :D $$\dfrac{1}{\log_ae} = \ln(a)$$ I'm solving some exercises and I ran up to this? Maybe it's really banal, but please explain me...

Comment: $\ln a \cdot \log_a e = \log_a e^{\ln a} = \log_a a = 1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\ln a = \log_e a$.
$$\log_a e = \frac{\ln e}{\ln a} = \frac 1{\ln a}$$

So, $\dfrac{1}{\log_a e} = \cdots $

Comment: Sweet like a candy +)

Answer (score 1):

We can prove $$\log_ab=\frac{\log_cb}{\log_ca}$$  where $a,c >0,\ne1$

$$\implies \log_ab\cdot\log_ba=\cdots=1$$

and conventionally [Natural logarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm)  is written as $\displaystyle \ln a$ which means $\displaystyle \log_ea$

Comment: You've got the [change of base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base) wrong; you've inverted the relationship, which should be $$\log_a b = \dfrac{\log_c b}{\log_c a}$$

Comment: @amWhy, typo rectified